# Accelerometer LIS2DE12 internal high-pass filter configurations

Tags: filter, accelerometer, digital-filter

I am working with an LIS2DE12 accelerometer. ODR is 5 kHz and I need to configure the internal high-pass filter to get rid of constant gravity value (around -16 on the Z axis). All configurations are done using this register:

[image]

I don't understand what mode and cut-off frequency I need for my application.

I have read the application note about these modes and it didn't make it easier to understand how to set it up.

What should I use as a reference value and how are the reference value, mode, and cut-off frequency related? What is the purpose of the reference value exactly if the filter filters out values depending on their change frequency? Maybe someone can explain every part of this register and its values, and how this filter works overall?